# How to remove space between content and left border in p tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to create an element by `P` tag which must be like this:

[image]

I create this by adding top and bottom border to a P tag but there is a little space between the content and left border of `P` tag: some thing like this:

[image]

How can I remove this space and start content just after tag boundry starts?

this is my Code:

```html
     <p style="color:#e72b78; font-weight: bold; border-top:#e72b78 2px solid; border-bottom:#e72b78 2px solid; ">
                        Primary end point:
     </p>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: display:table is the one with the more support that keep the block behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it fits but just set the width of the `p` to `fit-content`.

Edit: Check the browser support for `fit-content` here:
https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content

```css
p {
color:#e72b78; 
font-weight: bold; 
border-top: currentColor 2px solid; 
border-bottom: currentColor 2px solid;
width: fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;

}
```

```html
<p>
                    Primary end point:
 </p>
```

Edit: If you want the border to have the color of the font you can use the `currentColor` variable.

```html
<p style="color:#e72b78; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-top: currentColor 2px solid; 
    border-bottom: currentColor 2px solid;
    width: fit-content;
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    ">
                        Primary end point:
     </p>
```

If you have to support IE11 as well you can set `display: inline` for the  `p`  tag but that may cause some alignment issues what you have to fix as well:

```html
<p style="color:#e72b78; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    border-top: currentColor 2px solid; 
    border-bottom: currentColor 2px solid;
   display: inline;
    ">
                        Primary end point:
     </p>
```

Comment: dose it works in inline CSS? or it must add to the style tag?

Comment: Yes it should work. I added it as inline style. It might happen that some padding is inherited. In that case just add `padding: 0` as well

Comment: this does not work for me:(

Comment: Can you post the styles which are applied to this `p` tag?

Comment: my firefox inspect console shows a warning sign beside the width property with  "invalid property value"

Comment: it is just like the code you created here.

Comment: updated it with the FF prefix. Try if it works now

Comment: I add -moz prefix and it works

Comment: I added one more way to do it in case if you have to support IE11 as well. But I prefer the fit-content. It makes the code cleaner to me...